# Noise and heavy vibration from 4wd

Tags: noise, 4wd, daihatsu

I am driving Daihatsu Terios 1999..manual

There is green 4wd lock sign on dash board. Has noise...forward and backward shaking on heavy gears. It needs very frequent change of gears. I don't know what to do. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like your Daihatsu is stuck in 4wd mode. If so, the transfer case may not like it. Most 4wd systems are for off road use only. When in 4wd and the vehicle is turning, the transfer case will bind, causing the vehicle to buck and behave a lot like what you are suggesting. I'd try to get it out of 4wd mode and see if this helps anything.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer! One thing I forgot is that I am new to the car. The car is with manual transmission. How can I get out from 4 wd mode? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Daihatsu is stuck in 4wd mode. If so, the transfer case may not like it. Most 4wd systems are for off road use only. When in 4wd and the vehicle is turning, the transfer case will bind, causing the vehicle to buck and behave a lot like what you are suggesting. I'd try to get it out of 4wd mode and see if this helps anything.

> One thing I forgot is that I am new to the car. The car is with manual transmission. How can I get out from 4 wd mode?

Your Daihatsu comes as either full time 4wd or selectable 2wd/4wd. Since it is indicating it is in 4wd mode, there should be a switch on the dash. Ensure the vehicle is at a stop, put it in neutral, the flick the switch. Then the light should turn off.